# DynamoDB input broken item if putting items too fast?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm facing a weird phenomenal when putting items to DynamoDB.

It seems like if putting items too fast, DynamoDB can't put the whole data to the table(kinda like a broken data, it has partial attributes but with some weird values)?

I'm using the AWS JavaScript SDK to putting items, no errors shown up, everything seemed to work fine, but once I checked the data from web console, some of the inserted data was broken. Is this is related to write capacity units? (but no errors tell me it's caused by the write capacity units..) I could confirm the spike of my write capacity units was about 60/min, the setting is "on-demand".

I tried to slow down the putting speed with one second interval and with the exactly same data, the data could be inserted correctly...

Anyone knows why and how to fix this..?

Comment: 60 per minute is extremely slow. It is far more likely that you have some bug in your js code than that dynamo inserts corrupted/partial data.

Comment: Agreed that this is likely a bug in the code performing the write. Sounds like some shared object causing an undesirable behavior.  While AWS has bugs in their services like every software does, the one being described here is unlikely to be in DynamoDB given the scale and quality of the service.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no: If DynamoDB decides to throttle your requests because you exceeded your provisioned capacity or exceed their own hardware's capacity or whatever - it will refuse to do whole requests, or in the case of `BatchWriteItems` do some of the writes and not do others (and it will tell you which it did and which it didn't). DynamoDB will never write **part** of a request or corrupt parts of one attribute.

If you are seeing that, the most likely culprit is a bug in your own code that does the write. Maybe your own code is not thread-safe, so if your code is trying to prepare two items for writing concurrently, the code doing this preperation has a data race and results in a corrupt item to be written. Obviously, it is also possible that DynamoDB has a bug causing this, but it can't be as simple a bug as "writing more than 60 items a minute causes corruption" - if this were the case, everyone would have encountered this bug...